# Is there a Java class that can represent an arbitrary Javascript object?

Tags: java, javascript, collections

I'm looking for a java class that is able to represent a dynamic javascript object.  This is so that I can move from and to Json while providing easy access to the data.  I would like this class to have access methods similar to what you would expect in a javascript object.

```
Preferences p = new Preferences(...);

p.getString("a");
p.getInteger("a");
p.getObject("a");
```

All of the above would cast to the appropriate type or return null.  Now the key part should be able to be something like this:

```
p.getString("a.b.c");
p.getString("a[0].b.d[1]");
```

And so on.  Is there something already done that handles like this?

Answer (score 3):

If you're trying to translate between JSON and Java, [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) is a good bet.

Comment: +1 for Gson, it's a very good lib. To represent an arbitrary JS/JSON object with it, try [JsonObject](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonObject.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use HashMaps.. JavaScript object are just a little more than that..

If you need the extra methods for casting etc, you can write your own class `JsObject` or similarly named, which wraps a HashMap and provides those methods.

If all you want is to serialize deserialize between JSON and Java object try [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).